# Is it possible to use Visual Studio 2022 Test Explorer to run C unit test?

Tags: c, visual-studio, unit-testing, test-explorer

I would like to run ansi C unit tests in VS by mean of Test Explorer (not only with Console).

I saw that it's possible for C++ projects (https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2022), but I can't find any help about writing pure C test in Visual Studio.

Is it feasable? And in case how? Thx.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It an “ansi C unit test” a test whose source code is written in ANSI C? Or is it a test that tests whether the C implementation it is executed in conforms to ANSI C? Microsoft Visual Studio only recently moved to support C somewhat, and I am not aware how complete or good it is. Do you really need “pure C”? What do you mean by “pure”? Why do you want ANSI C, which is three decades old, rather than a modern standard C, like C 2018 or C 2011? What stops you from writing C code in the unit tests?

Comment: I'm using C99 for production and test code, but I guess it's not a matter. I can use also the last available standard for C. I need to run C unit tests in Visual Studio (with Test Explorer). Every example I found it uses a C++ project. It seems that there is no unit test framework for C that can be integrated with VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. See my [example](https://github.com/asm-jaime/TDDCByVisualStudio).
(To avoid LNK2019 error you shall include *.c to your test project, not *.h).